# Drawit vs Pixel

Tags: image, macos

if you have to choose between two image application on a mac [Drawit](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/drawit/index.html) ($38) or [Pixel](http://www.kanzelsberger.com/pixel/?page_id=5) ($46). Drawit is similar to Adobe fireworks while Pixel is like PhotoShop. Which will you choose and why.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because i mainly do web-design or graphics for the web my application of choice is Fireworks. It loads up quickly, supports vector design, exports for web and it's what I'm used to!

I think you need to decide what you are going to be using it for and what if any experience you have with either product.

Hope that helps.

Josh

Comment: i use fireworks mainly for my web design...don't really fancy PS but don't wont mind to adapt...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with them. I don't know either of them, but I have always worked with Fireworks for things as web design, as seemingly opposed to a lot of people who prefer Photoshop. I mostly use Photoshop for some more advanced image editing.